# How to convert crystal report to PDF without using ReportDocument

Tags: vb.net, loops, listview, multidimensional-array, ambiguous

Using VB.NET 2005, I have created a customized crystal report in which column title and data will get selected dynamically.

I am not using `ReportDocument` but directly creating an object to report class and assign the `datasource` to crystal report viewer.

So, I have to use only crystal report viewer to export. In which i am unable to convert.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking - it would be helpful if you post some of your code and illustrate exactly what's going wrong with it.

Comment: You **cannot do that**  - if you have a **Crystal Report**; you need to use the CR runtime to render and output it - no other way to do this .

Comment: I use crystal report viewer for viewing. But i am not using crystal report document for passing parameters. I create an object for crystal report and assign datasource to that object and then object to crystal report viewer.